# Remove menu Java Android

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I have removed action bar from my application and made it full screen with this line

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

but now I can`t remove menu from it,when i run the program and open menu program gets crashed.

Comment: If there's a crash, post the exception stacktrace from logcat, along with any code related with the exception.

Answer (score 2):

Write This Code between `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` and `setContentView(R.layout.main)`.

such as.

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Comment: I have written the same only this line you have written 2times requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

Answer (score 0):

you can modify AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
```